# Laravel New Middleware not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.4, laravel-middleware

### I have a problem in my project, i just try to fix in many hours but it still not working.

**I've created a new middleware - here is my code:**

```
    class CpanelAuthentication
        {
            public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'player')
            {
                if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect('cpanel');
                }
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
```

**i'm just config provider and guard too. - here is my auth.php**

```
    'guards' => [
                    'web' => [
                        'driver' => 'session',
                        'provider' => 'users',
                    ],

                    'api' => [
                        'driver' => 'token',
                        'provider' => 'users',
                    ],

                    'player' => [
                        'driver' => 'session',
                        'provider' => 'player',
                    ],
                ],

           'providers' => [
                'users' => [
                    'driver' => 'database',
                    'table' => 'tbl_users'
                ],

                'player' => [
                    'driver' => 'database',
                    'table' => 'tbl_player'
                ],
            ],
```

**And i register this middleware in Kernel.php too - Here is my Kernel.php**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],

        'player' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\CpanelAuthentication::class,
        ],
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'player' => \App\Http\Middleware\CpanelAuthentication::class
    ];
```

**And finaly i put this middleware in a route group like this:**

```
Route::group(['middleware'  => 'player'], function() {
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'cpanel', 'namespace' => 'Cpanel'], function() {
            Route::get('/', [
                'as'    => 'getCpanel',
                'uses'  => 'CpanelController@getCpanel'
            ]);
            Route::group(['prefix' => 'investment'], function() {
                Route::get('/', [
                    'as' => 'getCpanelInvestment',
                    'uses' => 'InvestmentController@getCpanelInvestment'
                ]);
            });
        });
    });
```

But the middleware not working. When i try to access the url

> cpanel/investment

It's still pass the middleware and redirect inside although the user is not authenticated!

Can anyone help me !

**Thanks so much !**

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `check()` which checks to see if a user is authenticated.

If you want to see if they aren't logged in, call `Auth::guard($guard)->guest()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Middleware:**

```
 class CpanelAuthentication
   {
            public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'player')
            {
                if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                     return $next($request);
                }
                 return redirect('/login');
            }
    }
```

**Route:**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['App\Http\Middleware\CpanelAuthentication']], function () {
         //routes
});
```

Try without registering in kernel